# How to resove label overlapping issue for React Material UI auto complete component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to react material UI. I want floating label for auto complete component. but after selecting any value from the auto complete options label should stick on the top.
Please goto [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pyl0wqq17) see the actual problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to update the property of select element, after selection is made. For that I am using the state `shrink`, which is `false` initially, that will set `true` once the item is selected. If the state `shrink` is `true`, then `InputLabelProps` is set with `{shrink: true}`. Otherwise empty object is set.

```
state = {
    single: null,
    multi: null,
    shrink:false //Newly added
};    

handleChange = name => value => {
    this.setState({
       [name]: value
    });

    this.setState({shrink:true}); //Newly added
}; 

<Select
    classes={classes}
    styles={selectStyles}
    options={suggestions}
    components={components}
    value={this.state.single}
    onChange={this.handleChange("single")}
    placeholder="Search a country (start with a)"
    textFieldProps={{
        label: "Label",
        InputLabelProps: this.state.shrink?{shrink:true}:{} //Modified line
    }}
/>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/93l3wxjqv4)

Comment: I want floater label not the static one, such that if the value is not selected or empty then label will take position of placeholder. like this https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/#textfield

Comment: Now answer is updated. This should work as intended.

Comment: I've heard that this is a bug. Does anyone know if this bug is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

[shashidhara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1925943/shashidhara) is right. I used the below code

```
<InputLabel id={attributeGroupAttribute.AttributeId+'_label'} 
                        className='bg-white' shrink={selectedValue !== null && selectedValue !== ''}
                        >{attributeDetails.Name}</InputLabel>
```

This was driving me nuts. Thanks a ton. The key part is the code below

```
shrink={selectedValue !== null && selectedValue !== ''}
```